# Justify if True or False $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\left(-|x|\le x\le |x|\right)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, absolute-value

I need some hints on how to solve this

> $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\left(-|x|\le x\le |x|\right)$$

Comment: Do you think that you should be trying to prove it, or trying to find a counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:
$$|x|=\max(x,-x) \tag1$$
$$-\max(a,b)=\min(-a,-b) \tag2$$

Comment: Try by cases. $x\geq 0$ and $x<0$.